# What's the difference between letters and arrows keycodes?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keycode

```
var keyPressed = function() {
    key[keyCode] = true;
};
var keyReleased = function() {
    key[keyCode] = false;
};
```

Why I can press more than one arrow keycode at once, and can't do it with the letters? I'm moving a player and, using WASD instead of arrows, I can't press <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> at the same time (diagonal), because when I press <kbd>W</kbd> and then <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> breaks <kbd>W</kbd>. It's only possible to go <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> or <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>.. But with the same code, with the arrows, I can hold them together and go to the diagonal.

I've concluded that there is some difference between arrows and input/letters-keyCodes. What's the difference? How can I press two letters at the very same time?

Comment: The difference is in the events you use. `keypress` works different than `keydown` and `keyup`. If you're detecting keycodes you don't want `keypress`. From your last question this seems to be the issue.

Comment: What event are you using?

Comment: Some keyboard vendors advertise [anti-ghosting](https://www.microsoft.com/applied-sciences/projects/anti-ghosting-demo/) features so there must be a difference at hardware level.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `onkeypress`, like:

```
var doc = document;
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
E('yourElementId').onkeypress = function(ev){
  var e = ev || event;
  var kc = e.keycode;
  if(kc == 87 || kc == 38){
    // W or up
  }
  if(kc == 68 || kc == 39){
    // D or right
  }
  if(kc == 83 || kc == 40){
    // S or down
  }
  if(kc == 65 || kc == 37){
    // A or left
  }
}
```